# What's the purpose of UrlDispatcher's ResourcesView and RoutesView in aiohttp?

Tags: aiohttp

I'm looking at [UrlDispatcher.resources()](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/28f15195c533a89118783f2db69c23a281357370/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py#L823) and [UrlDispatcher.routes()](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/28f15195c533a89118783f2db69c23a281357370/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py#L826) methods.

They return [ResourcesView](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/28f15195c533a89118783f2db69c23a281357370/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py#L752) and [RoutesView](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/28f15195c533a89118783f2db69c23a281357370/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py#L767) objects respectively.

I wonder, what's the purpose of those views?

Can I use them to display the list of endpoint available in my service in a similar manner to Django or Django REST Framework?

I assume, they are not proper web views, cause they don't have methods, corresponding to http methods, e.g. `get(request)` and don't inherit from `View` or `AbstractView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These views are immutable objects used to lookup/iterate routes and resources.

Like `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()`.

Internally, aiohttp router is organized in the following way.

Lets assume we have a route table like:

```
app.add_routes([
    web.get('/path1', handler1),
    web.post('/path1', handler2),
    web.get('/path2', handler3)])
```

Internally we have two resources: `/path1` and `/path2`.

`/path1` resource has two routes for `GET` and `POST` HTTP methods.

`/path2` has only a route for `GET`.

`app.router.resources` allows iteration over resources, `app.router.routes` iterates one level deeper.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Andrew, I love aiohttp. So, I took it right, they are not views in MVC/django sense. They are container/iterator-like objects for utility purposes. In the codebase they are located next to View object (which IS a proper MVC/django view), which confused me a bit, I thought they are web views, too. :)

Comment: Your understanding is right: they are not MVC views

Comment: Django doens't use the term MVC. The Django way is MVT Model-View-Template. In this sense, aiohttp doesn't embed a Template library you can choose your favorite template library. Route handlers are what Django calls View.